# Incorrect Top? or manpage?

Tags: linux, centos, top, scheduling, priority

According to `top`'s manpage:

```
16. PR  --  Priority
       The scheduling priority of the task.  If you see `rt' in this 
field, it means the task is running under real time scheduling priority.

       Under linux, real time priority is somewhat misleading since 
traditionally the operating itself was not preemptible.  And while the 2.6
kernel can be made mostly preemptible, it is not always so.
```

I attempted to change a running process to have realtime priority:

```
$ sudo chrt -f -p 1 2179
$ chrt -m
SCHED_OTHER min/max priority    : 0/0
SCHED_FIFO min/max priority : 1/99
SCHED_RR min/max priority   : 1/99
SCHED_BATCH min/max priority    : 0/0
SCHED_IDLE min/max priority : 0/0
SCHED_DEADLINE min/max priority : 0/0
$ chrt -p 2179
pid 2179's current scheduling policy: SCHED_FIFO
pid 2179's current scheduling priority: 1
$
```

But `top` shows

```
Tasks: 255 total,   3 running, 252 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.4 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 19658969+total, 19371019+free,  2405528 used,   473984 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  4194300 free,        0 used. 19352804+avail Mem 

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  2179 myuser      -2   0   25552   2892   2648 R 100.0  0.0  67:16.22 my_application
```

It shows -2 as priority.  Should it be `rt`?

I do see some process like `migration/0` has `rt` as the priority tho.